# During boot, I only see a dark aubergine screen - how can I make plymouth work?

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, plymouth

In Natty, during boot I only see a dark aubergine screen, nothing on it. That is irritating, because I don't know whether the computer still runs or not.

So how can I display the normal "ubuntu" plymouth bootscreen?
(I use the nvidia proprietary driver.)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/how-to-get-plymouth-working-with-nvidia.html
This has always worked for me.
But if it's really only about knowing if the computer is still running, just remove the `quiet` and `splash` parameters from *grub.cfg*.

Comment: I've already suggested the same, and it did not work for the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the open source drivers, you'll have a poor performance? I mean, according on what you usually do in your PC, nouveau drivers are a solution for you?

Regards!

Comment: I don't know which driver I use. In the "additional drivers" app, it is told, that the nvidia current driver is activated, but not in use. however, I have all compiz effects....